# .htaccess - Trying to NOT rewrite one file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've read some .htaccess tutorials but can't figure out this easy task.
I have a site that typically routes every request to index.php.
But I have one specific file (upload_photo.php) that I want it to simply execute without rerouting to index.php.  Below is my htacess file with an entry for upload_photo.php that screws up everything.  What am I doing wrong?

```
# AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
# AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
#Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule upload_photo.php upload_photo.php [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]

ErrorDocument 404 /page-unavailable/

<files ~ "\.tpl$">
order deny,allow
allow from none
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: May be better on serverfault.com

Comment: "screws up everything" is hardly a technical analysis

Comment: Well screws up everything means, in the above .htacess file, the when I have that line containing upoad_photo.php enabled, much of my .css files and some images get rerouted to page-unavailable.  I think it is anything outside that particular directory structure that gets page-unavailable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original rewrite you had:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

does something like this:

Configuration:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
```

if the path requested is not a file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

if the path requested is not a directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

then rewrite to index.php

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

So, if your file `upload_photo.php` really exist in same directory where `index.php` is, you don't need to change the original rewrite. 
The correct file .php will be referenced automatically, because the rewrite to index.php will be executed only if the requested resource (file or directory) does not exist.

So there is no need to add this:

```
RewriteRule upload_photo.php upload_photo.php [L]
```

Comment: Oh, duh.  I just assumed all php files were being redirected.  Silly me.  Yea, I tried it and it works fine.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteRule upload_photo\.php - [L]
```

`-` means "don't rewrite", `L` stops other rules from being processed when this rule matches. Put it before the general rewrite rule.

In your case it screws up because the `RewriteCond`s only apply to one `RewriteRule` at a time.

Comment: +1, simple and clear answer

Comment: Moving it up above the RewriteCon worked great.